# What is an appropriate way of getting and setting the display member of a bound DataGridViewComboboxCell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a WinForms application containing a DataGridView with a column that is databound to a database table. The table contains only an ID and a string. The display member is set to the string and the value member is set to the ID.

Firstly, based on the user input, I want to be able to programatically change the selected item in the combobox. Ideally, I would have some sort of method, `private void changeSelectedItem(int id)` , that would match that ID with the appropriate display member string and display it in the combobox. Perhaps this sort of functionality is already built into the combobox but so far it has eluded me.

Secondly, the user may choose to override the action described above by choosing a different item from the combobox. When the user clicks on a different item inside of the combobox, I would like to be able to retrieve the ID (value member) of the selected item.

I have searched online for help with this matter but every solution I found didn't work. Among the solutions I found are:

- changing the value of the cell iself (which didn't exactly choose an item from the list of items it just overwrites the string that is displayed in the cell...)
- choosing an item from the `Items` property of the combobox but, since it is databound, it is empty.
- Using the `EditingControl` to retrieve this data. Since the combobox does not even have focus, I cannot access the `EditingControl`. This could, however, be used for the second requirement I have.
- And many other variations on the same as the above.

So how do you get and set the selected item of a databound DataGridViewComboBoxCell?

Comment: Setting the Value to the ID you want is really all you should need to do. The Text of that id's string will appear automtically, prvided the ID is valid. If it doesn't you have broken something..

Comment: Ok, I assumed that setting the value would just print the int as a string. I also noticed that if I try and get the value, I get the ID... It's the simplest things that get me I suppose. Indeed it works. Thank you!